What does なんたら mean?
I came across

昨日のハイドロなんたらとかいう怖い女の子だ

Which from an official translations means

Its that scary girl from yesterday called Hydro-glerpadoodle

Am I right in assuming that なんたら is a filler word for when you cant recall an exact name/word?
I tried googling but couldn't find anything about it

I don’t know if English is your first language, but in case it’s not, let me just add that “Hydro-glerpadoodle” is a really bizarre translation. Glerpadoodle is not a word, and it doesn’t conjure up images of a filler for ‘I can’t remember the actual name’. It conjures up images of being silly, derpy, playful and clumsy – a very odd pairing with the adjective ‘scary’. A more natural translation would have been “Hydro-whatsherface”, “Hydro-thingummy”, “Hydro-whatchamacallit” – or indeed just “Hydro-something”.

haha yeah also through glerpadoodle was a bit weird. Its actually a fan translation so could be a non-native.

According to Jisho, my favorite Japanese dictionary, it is a filler word.

なんたらかんたら
Expressions (phrases, clauses, etc.)

something or other; what-do-you-call-it; what-do-you-call-them​Onomatopoeic >or mimetic word
Expressions (phrases, clauses, etc.)
blah blah blah; yada yada yada​Onomatopoeic or mimetic word



Thank you. I always forget to look in the most obvious places..

It's a synonym of 何とかかんとか, which is abbreviated to なんとか. And your assumption is correct, you can use it to fill in when you don't recall the whole of a word, name, expression, etc.
